# Running Many R Regressions

Tags: r, function

I have data such as:

```
    data = data.frame(Y1 = runif(10000),
    E1=runif(10000),
    E2=runif(10000),
    E3=runif(10000),
    AQ=runif(10000),
    WE=runif(10000),
    SZ=runif(10000),
    PO=runif(10000),
    LL=runif(10000),
    SCHOOL=sample(1:2, r = T),
    CLASS = sample(1:4, r = T))
```

My goals is to fit these simple regression models:

```
Y1 = Ei + AQ
Y1 = Ei + AQ + WE + SZ
Y1 = Ei + AQ + WE + SZ + PO + LL
```

for every combination of SCHOOL and CLASS, this gives 3 * 2 * 4 = 24 MODELS.

From all the models I just wish to save the coefficient and p value and confidence interval for all the independent variables.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Can you post your attempt / issue(s)?

Comment: Caution: `SCHOOL=sample(1:2, r = T)` may well result in a column entirely filled with 2 or 1, as the sample may become the vector `c(2,2) `or `c(1,1)`. If you want random values throughout the dataset, use `SCHOOL=sample(1:2, 10000, r = T)`. The same goes for the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.0.0
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
lst1 <- list("AQ", c("AQ", "WE", "SZ"),
      c("AQ", "WE", "SZ", "PO", "LL"))
nm1 <- grep("^E\\d+$", names(data), value = TRUE)
fmlst <- do.call(c, lapply(lst1, function(vec)
   lapply(nm1, function(nm) reformulate(c(nm, vec), response = 'Y1'))))

data %>%
    nest_by(SCHOOL, CLASS) %>% 
    summarise(lmmodels = map(fmlst, ~  lm(.x, data = data)), 
              tidyout = map(lmmodels, tidy))
# A tibble: 36 x 4
# Groups:   SCHOOL, CLASS [4]
#   SCHOOL CLASS lmmodels tidyout         
#    <int> <int> <list>   <list>          
# 1      1     2 <lm>     <tibble [3 × 5]>
# 2      1     2 <lm>     <tibble [3 × 5]>
# 3      1     2 <lm>     <tibble [3 × 5]>
# 4      1     2 <lm>     <tibble [5 × 5]>
# 5      1     2 <lm>     <tibble [5 × 5]>
# 6      1     2 <lm>     <tibble [5 × 5]>
# 7      1     2 <lm>     <tibble [7 × 5]>
# 8      1     2 <lm>     <tibble [7 × 5]>
# 9      1     2 <lm>     <tibble [7 × 5]>
#10      1     4 <lm>     <tibble [3 × 5]>
# … with 26 more rows
```

Comment: thank you so much this is really excellent; how do i access or store the results ? I try indexing [] but cannot get it..specifically I am hoping for the estimate, pvalue and Confidence Intervals all in one data.frame

Comment: @bvowe.  It is `list` column.  So you can loop over the list with `lapply` or `map` from `purrr`, i.e. if  'out' is the output, then `lapply(out$tidyout, function(x) x$yourcolumnname)`

Comment: i tried, TEST=data %>%
  nest_by(SCHOOL, CLASS) %>% 
  summarise(lmmodels = map(fmlst, ~  lm(.x, data = data)), 
            tidyout = map(lmmodels, tidy))


lapply(TEST$tidyout, function(x) x$coefficients)

Comment: @bvowe you can do `map(TEST$tidyout, ~ .x$estimate)` or `map(TEST$tidyout, ~ .x$p.value)`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass regression models to `lm()` as characters. So, you just need to loop through your variable names and update the model for each run:

```
results = list()
models = list()

model = "Y1 ~ "
for(i in 2:length(names(data))){
  model = paste(model, '+', names(data)[i])
  models[i] = model
  results[i] = list(lm(model,data=data))
}
```

This code extends the regression equation at each iteration and stores the model equation and the regression results in lists.

EDIT: Sorry, I misread the initial post and proposed regression models that were not demanded.

The code below computes the three different regression models for all E-Variables and for all classes and schools individually:

```
counter = 1
models = c()
results = list()

for(s in unique(data$SCHOOL)){
  for(c in unique(data$CLASS)){
    subset = data[data$SCHOOL==s & data$CLASS==c,]
    for(ei in 1:3){
      for(dv in c("AQ", "AQ + WE + SZ", "AQ + WE + SZ + PO + LL")){
        model = paste("Y1 ~ E",ei," + ",dv,sep="")
        models[counter] = paste(model,"for SCHOOL=",s," and CLASS=",c)
        r = lm(model,data=subset)
        results[counter]=list(r)
        counter=counter+1
      }
    }
      
  }
}
```

The third model in this loop would be:

```
> models[[3]]
[1] "Y1 ~ E1 + AQ + WE + SZ + PO + LL for SCHOOL= 2  and CLASS= 3"
> summary(results[[3]])

Call:
lm(formula = model, data = subset)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.53038 -0.24119 -0.00201  0.24940  0.54257 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.445346   0.024633  18.079  < 2e-16 ***
E1           0.035352   0.019676   1.797 0.072504 .  
AQ           0.017344   0.019958   0.869 0.384919    
WE          -0.002737   0.019820  -0.138 0.890174    
SZ           0.067423   0.020079   3.358 0.000797 ***
PO          -0.029509   0.019897  -1.483 0.138188    
LL           0.018326   0.019483   0.941 0.346988    
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2863 on 2493 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.007309,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.00492 
F-statistic: 3.059 on 6 and 2493 DF,  p-value: 0.005518
```

Comment: thank you so much that is really quite helpful. I do have a question however. Your code includes E1 and E2 and E3 in the models but I hope to fit the models like in the question, where E1 and E2 and E3 are all in separate models, and the models are estimated by groups.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. The edit fixed it. Now, it loops through different subsets of the data and through different models.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it like this

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(
  Y1 = runif(10000),
  E1 = runif(10000),
  E2 = runif(10000),
  E3 = runif(10000),
  AQ = runif(10000),
  WE = runif(10000),
  SZ = runif(10000),
  PO = runif(10000),
  LL = runif(10000),
  SCHOOL = sample(1:2, size = 10000, r = T),
  CLASS = sample(1:4, size = 10000, r = T)
)




xx <- data %>%
  nest_by(SCHOOL, CLASS) %>%
  mutate(
    model1 = list(lm(Y1 ~ E1 + AQ, data = data)),
    model2 = list(lm(Y1 ~ E1 + AQ + WE + SZ, data = data)),
    model3 = list(lm(Y1 ~ E1 + AQ + WE + SZ + PO + LL, data = data))
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("model"), .fns = ~ list(broom::tidy(.x))))

xx$model1
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)   0.511     0.0215    23.8   5.04e-103
#> 2 E1           -0.0188    0.0277    -0.680 4.97e-  1
#> 3 AQ           -0.0152    0.0279    -0.546 5.85e-  1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)   0.496     0.0209    23.7   2.05e-103
#> 2 E1            0.0239    0.0273     0.875 3.81e-  1
#> 3 AQ           -0.0162    0.0274    -0.591 5.54e-  1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.489      0.0217    22.6   9.05e-95
#> 2 E1          -0.00647    0.0288    -0.225 8.22e- 1
#> 3 AQ           0.0315     0.0290     1.09  2.76e- 1
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.521      0.0221    23.6   1.21e-102
#> 2 E1          -0.0264     0.0278    -0.949 3.43e-  1
#> 3 AQ          -0.00902    0.0287    -0.315 7.53e-  1
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.521      0.0213    24.5   1.49e-108
#> 2 E1           0.00735    0.0282     0.260 7.95e-  1
#> 3 AQ          -0.0257     0.0280    -0.917 3.59e-  1
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.490      0.0218    22.5   3.92e-94
#> 2 E1           0.0359     0.0285     1.26  2.09e- 1
#> 3 AQ          -0.00878    0.0288    -0.305 7.61e- 1
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)   0.529     0.0217     24.4  3.04e-107
#> 2 E1           -0.0498    0.0287     -1.74 8.28e-  2
#> 3 AQ           -0.0341    0.0289     -1.18 2.38e-  1
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.532      0.0229   23.3    5.57e-99
#> 2 E1          -0.0760     0.0296   -2.56   1.04e- 2
#> 3 AQ          -0.00109    0.0286   -0.0382 9.70e- 1

xx$model2
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)   0.507     0.0293    17.3   5.37e-60
#> 2 E1           -0.0183    0.0277    -0.660 5.09e- 1
#> 3 AQ           -0.0143    0.0279    -0.514 6.07e- 1
#> 4 WE           -0.0288    0.0283    -1.02  3.09e- 1
#> 5 SZ            0.0378    0.0287     1.32  1.89e- 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.504      0.0288   17.5    8.12e-62
#> 2 E1           0.0238     0.0273    0.871  3.84e- 1
#> 3 AQ          -0.0164     0.0274   -0.599  5.49e- 1
#> 4 WE          -0.0135     0.0275   -0.489  6.25e- 1
#> 5 SZ          -0.00165    0.0280   -0.0589 9.53e- 1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.486      0.0308    15.8   3.03e-51
#> 2 E1          -0.00598    0.0288    -0.208 8.36e- 1
#> 3 AQ           0.0316     0.0290     1.09  2.77e- 1
#> 4 WE           0.0135     0.0287     0.469 6.39e- 1
#> 5 SZ          -0.00838    0.0286    -0.293 7.69e- 1
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.516      0.0299    17.3   4.36e-60
#> 2 E1          -0.0255     0.0279    -0.916 3.60e- 1
#> 3 AQ          -0.00908    0.0287    -0.317 7.52e- 1
#> 4 WE          -0.00593    0.0278    -0.213 8.31e- 1
#> 5 SZ           0.0157     0.0280     0.559 5.76e- 1
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.512      0.0293    17.5   1.93e-61
#> 2 E1           0.00714    0.0282     0.253 8.00e- 1
#> 3 AQ          -0.0261     0.0280    -0.933 3.51e- 1
#> 4 WE           0.0464     0.0282     1.64  1.01e- 1
#> 5 SZ          -0.0283     0.0283    -1.00  3.16e- 1
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   term         estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.500       0.0299   16.7    1.73e-56
#> 2 E1           0.0356      0.0286    1.25   2.13e- 1
#> 3 AQ          -0.00939     0.0289   -0.325  7.45e- 1
#> 4 WE          -0.0184      0.0290   -0.633  5.27e- 1
#> 5 SZ          -0.000915    0.0291   -0.0314 9.75e- 1
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)   0.494     0.0307    16.1   6.12e-53
#> 2 E1           -0.0497    0.0287    -1.73  8.35e- 2
#> 3 AQ           -0.0297    0.0290    -1.02  3.06e- 1
#> 4 WE            0.0210    0.0295     0.714 4.76e- 1
#> 5 SZ            0.0452    0.0287     1.58  1.15e- 1
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.516      0.0306   16.9    2.41e-57
#> 2 E1          -0.0760     0.0296   -2.57   1.04e- 2
#> 3 AQ          -0.00122    0.0286   -0.0425 9.66e- 1
#> 4 WE           0.0396     0.0289    1.37   1.70e- 1
#> 5 SZ          -0.00644    0.0292   -0.220  8.26e- 1

xx$model3
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.515      0.0355    14.5   3.63e-44
#> 2 E1          -0.0184     0.0278    -0.662 5.08e- 1
#> 3 AQ          -0.0143     0.0279    -0.513 6.08e- 1
#> 4 WE          -0.0286     0.0283    -1.01  3.12e- 1
#> 5 SZ           0.0374     0.0288     1.30  1.94e- 1
#> 6 PO          -0.00520    0.0282    -0.185 8.53e- 1
#> 7 LL          -0.0117     0.0280    -0.419 6.75e- 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.493      0.0348   14.1    2.24e-42
#> 2 E1           0.0244     0.0273    0.893  3.72e- 1
#> 3 AQ          -0.0174     0.0274   -0.635  5.26e- 1
#> 4 WE          -0.0124     0.0275   -0.452  6.52e- 1
#> 5 SZ          -0.00223    0.0280   -0.0795 9.37e- 1
#> 6 PO           0.0317     0.0275    1.15   2.50e- 1
#> 7 LL          -0.0103     0.0272   -0.380  7.04e- 1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.469      0.0366    12.8   2.04e-35
#> 2 E1          -0.00503    0.0288    -0.175 8.61e- 1
#> 3 AQ           0.0302     0.0290     1.04  2.98e- 1
#> 4 WE           0.0132     0.0287     0.460 6.46e- 1
#> 5 SZ          -0.00696    0.0286    -0.244 8.08e- 1
#> 6 PO          -0.0194     0.0281    -0.691 4.89e- 1
#> 7 LL           0.0547     0.0281     1.95  5.18e- 2
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.525      0.0372    14.1   4.15e-42
#> 2 E1          -0.0258     0.0279    -0.923 3.56e- 1
#> 3 AQ          -0.0101     0.0288    -0.353 7.24e- 1
#> 4 WE          -0.00707    0.0278    -0.254 7.99e- 1
#> 5 SZ           0.0155     0.0280     0.552 5.81e- 1
#> 6 PO           0.0171     0.0279     0.613 5.40e- 1
#> 7 LL          -0.0327     0.0282    -1.16  2.47e- 1
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.501      0.0366    13.7   5.28e-40
#> 2 E1           0.00872    0.0282     0.309 7.57e- 1
#> 3 AQ          -0.0249     0.0280    -0.888 3.75e- 1
#> 4 WE           0.0455     0.0283     1.61  1.08e- 1
#> 5 SZ          -0.0258     0.0283    -0.913 3.61e- 1
#> 6 PO          -0.0287     0.0281    -1.02  3.07e- 1
#> 7 LL           0.0456     0.0284     1.60  1.09e- 1
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   term         estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.514       0.0363   14.2    2.57e-42
#> 2 E1           0.0361      0.0285    1.26   2.06e- 1
#> 3 AQ          -0.00899     0.0288   -0.312  7.55e- 1
#> 4 WE          -0.0167      0.0290   -0.576  5.65e- 1
#> 5 SZ           0.000892    0.0291    0.0307 9.76e- 1
#> 6 PO          -0.0644      0.0288   -2.24   2.56e- 2
#> 7 LL           0.0325      0.0291    1.12   2.64e- 1
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   term         estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.484       0.0366   13.2    1.74e-37
#> 2 E1          -0.0508      0.0288   -1.76   7.85e- 2
#> 3 AQ          -0.0302      0.0291   -1.04   3.00e- 1
#> 4 WE           0.0214      0.0295    0.725  4.68e- 1
#> 5 SZ           0.0459      0.0287    1.60   1.10e- 1
#> 6 PO           0.0203      0.0287    0.708  4.79e- 1
#> 7 LL           0.000378    0.0288    0.0131 9.90e- 1
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  0.503      0.0376   13.4    3.27e-38
#> 2 E1          -0.0761     0.0297   -2.57   1.04e- 2
#> 3 AQ          -0.00115    0.0286   -0.0400 9.68e- 1
#> 4 WE           0.0400     0.0289    1.38   1.67e- 1
#> 5 SZ          -0.00594    0.0293   -0.203  8.39e- 1
#> 6 PO           0.0208     0.0288    0.721  4.71e- 1
#> 7 LL           0.00232    0.0295    0.0786 9.37e- 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>